# Joomla without index.php (301 redirect)

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I recently have started project in Joomla. I had to remove index.php from it (it was some checkbox in Configuration settings). I have found how to do it. And currently really all URLs are created without index.php.

However, I can directly enter into URL http://mywebsite.com/index.php/article-name and it is not rewriting to http://mywebsite.com/article-name.
If I have a menu, then URL is creating correctly (http://mywebsite.com/article-name - so without index.php).

So the question is:
how to create htaccess redirect for website with index.php to website without index.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're internally routing stuff to index.php, you'll have to match against the actual request:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /index\.php/[^\ ]+
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your global configuration page and make following changes:

1. Turn on SEF (Search Engine Friendly) URLs option.
2. Say Yes to Apache mod_rewrite
3. Say No to Add Suffix to URL
4. Say No to Unicode Aliases
5. Say No to include site name in Page Title.

Also change htaccess.txt to .htaccess. Now add your new redirect code at the point which says “Redirect Goes Here”.

**Code**:

#### Begin - 301 Redirect

#

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*(index|home).html?\ HTTP/

RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)(index|home).html?$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^POST

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index.php\ HTTP/

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}>s ^(443>(s)|[0-9]+>s)$

RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index.php$ http%2://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.example.com)?$

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#

#### End - 301 Redirect

Note: Remove www.example.com with your site name.